# How to display a spatial field on a map?

Tags: django, openlayers, postgis, openstreetmap

I have a spatial field in my Django model.  I want to display this field on a map.  How to do it?  It works just fine in Django Admin with Django built-in OSMWidget and OpenLayers.

If I try to access the spatial field in my template it is of this format:

```
SRID=4326;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON ((54.57842969715517 23.34800720214843, 54.53144199643833 23.29547882080078, 54.52964902093564 23.38096618652343, 54.57444978782305 23.40499877929688, 54.57842969715517 23.34800720214843)))
```

Comment: If you strip out the SRID part you could read that in OpenLayers as a WKT feature https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-76i38

Answer (score 0):

The format is WKT (Well Known Text), and with OL you just need to use `ol.format.WKT` to read all or individual features ([OL API - WKT format](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WKT-WKT.html)).

I put this example for you, based on OL example [OL Examples - WKT](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wkt.html). I wanted to show a particularity or `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` that it can contain different types of geometry, witch is not always wanted.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>WKT Geometry</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const wkt = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION('+
        'MULTIPOINT(-2 3 , -2 2),'+
        'LINESTRING(5 5 ,10 10),'+
        'POLYGON((-7 4.2,-7.1 5,-7.1 4.3,-7 4.2)))';

      const format = new ol.format.WKT();

      const features = format.readFeatures(wkt, {
        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      });

      const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ff3333',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#ff3333'
            })
          })
        })
      });

      const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 5]),
          zoom: 5
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```