# How can I view polygon openlayers

Tags: javascript, html, c, openlayers

How can I show the polygon saved in my database in wkt format on the map, can you help? I don't know how to do it because I just started the mapping business

After making such a drawing, I make a registration, but I don't know how to view the record in the database on the map.

I'm trying to view it as follows, but I can't pull my wkt type coordinate.

```
function ListPolygon() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Home/ListPolygon",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var _features = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var format = new ol.format.WKT();
                var _poly = response[i];
                var _id = _poly.Id;
                var wkt = _poly.MahalleKordinant;
                var _geo = new ol.geom.Polygon([format.readFeature(wkt)]);


                var featurething = new ol.Feature({
                    name: "Mahalle",
                    geometry: _geo,
                });
                featurething.setId(_id)

                var _style = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 200, 155, 0.8)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#ffcc33',
                        width: 3
                    }),
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 6,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#ffcc33'
                        })
                    })
                });
                featurething.setStyle(_style);

                _features.push(featurething);
            }
            var _polysource = mahalle_layer.getSource().getExtent();

            _polysource.addFeatures(_features);
        },

        error: function () {
            alert("Hata");
        },

    });
}

ListPolygon();
```

I edited it this way but the console gets this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hipdF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjLr3.png)

Comment: If you put the WKT text into the database, you need to get that text back out, transfer it to your map then load it.  Related question: [How to display a spatial field on a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61460102/how-to-display-a-spatial-field-on-a-map)

Comment: so how do i get back this text in my database @geocodezip

Comment: That is a very broad question (and doesn't really have anything to do with openlayers)..  There should be lots of tutorials out there on how to query data and return it to a web page via AJAX.

Comment: I'm bothering you too, but I edited it this way I get this error on the console  what should I do @geocodezip